# rsync error "rsync: failed to set times on "directory" : No such file or directory (2)

Tags: permissions, backup, rsync

My backup throws these errors

> rsync: failed to set times on "directory" : No such file or directory (2)

Seemingly exclusively on symlinks when running with the flags `rsync -avx`

Some of the symlinks point to files in the same directory as the link, and some for example one in `~/.kde` point to stuff like `/run/user/1000/ksocket-username`.

I don't see any reason why this error would arise.
Would be thankful for any tips.

Here are some examples:

```
rsync: failed to set times on "/home/username/dragon/backup/backup.tmp/.config/autostart-scripts/setxkb.sh": No such file or directory (2)
```

This link ist pointing at /home/username/setxkb.sh

```
rsync: failed to set times on "/home/username/dragon/backup/backup.tmp/vmd1.9.3/lib/vmd/libavcodec.so": No such file or directory (2)
```

This link is pointing at libavcodec.so.56.13.100 in the same directory.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure on the reason of the error, but you can skip transferring times of symlinks using the -J option.

From the rsync man page:

> -J, --omit-link-times
>   This tells rsync to omit symlinks when it is preserving modification times (see --times).

Comment: The man page is available at https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rsync.1.html